# Using php routing with a href #id

Tags: php, routes

I have php routing set up, I'm using the case/break method.

Taking a simple example, the user clicks on a `/home` link and is directed to the home page `home.php`. In this there is `<a href='#id'>click me</a>` because it is not recognised the 404 kicks in. How do I allow for these reference links to work, bypassing the router switch?

html - code for #feature

```
  <!-- Navigation section -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Bonify</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#top" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#feature" class="smoothScroll">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#menu" class="smoothScroll">Enter the collection</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#gallery" class="smoothScroll">Gallery</a></li>
          <!--li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li-->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Feature section -->
  <section id="feature" class="parallax-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
          <div class="wow fadeInUp section-title" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
            <h2>A Simple Question</h2>
            <h4>a Technological Solution</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
```

route

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($Request) {
  case '/home' :
  require __DIR__ . '\site\home.php';
  break;

  default:
  http_response_code(404);
  require __DIR__ . '/404.php';
  break;
```

Comment: Where does the variable `$Request` come from? A page `#anchor` is never sent to the server at all, PHP has no access to it. Anchors only serve as hints to the browser and are not transmitted with HTTP GET or POST requests.

Comment: `$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` I'll add it to the OP

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The page anchor works in the site without the router, but in the new site the page anchors do not appear to be responsive which clicked. Nothing seems to happen.

Comment: When you use an anchor-only link like `<a href='#id'>click me</a>`, it should never invoke PHP at all, the browser never even sends a request to your script and instead should just jump on the page. You should check the output from `print_r($Request);` in the circumstance where your router 404's.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've added the html, now looking at the output from `print_r($Request); `

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `php print_r($Request); ` gives the expected url. On the page I'm testing there is no other php, for that page all the php is in the route file.

Comment: Which link specifically (or all of them) works improperly? None of those `#` links should ever reach your PHP, unless you have some JS framework adding extra magic. If you open your browser's network console, you should see no requests back to the php web server when you hit one of those links, while if you hit a link with no href like `href=""`, it should reload whatever is in the address bar. Look carefully at things like CSS href attributes or img tags with empty src=. Those would cause requests back to the PHP which may be mishandled by the router.